# iPhone Photos thinks both my kids are the same person

Tags: iphone, photos.app

In the iPhone photos app, my two boys were labelled as the same person (the older one). I've gone through about a dozen photos and done the 'This is not John' -> Rename Person routine.

Is there a way to do this quicker so I don't have to go through every photo it has categorised as John?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two people combined into one entry, the following steps should clear it up:

1. Select the existing entry and open up the "Review Photos" menu

   - on iOS, this is under the three-dot (•••) menu
   - on macOS, the option appears to not be present
2. A subset of photos will appear. These are the ones the phone considered "confirmed" photos of the person. Determine which person to keep on this record (Person A from now on - probably the one that appears more) and deselect all the photos of the other person (Person B). When you're done, tap "Done."
3. Find a photo in your photo library of Person B and tag them. If they're already tagged as Person A, rename them. Open their photo card and repeat the "Review Photos" step and ensure that all their photos are of Person B. Deselect any of Person A.
4. Now, bring up Person A's Review Photos list again and go to the bottom. Tap Review More Photos and answer all the prompts Yes/No whether they're Person A. If no photos appear to be confirmed, just tap Done and exit out.
5. Once you've done Person A, repeat the previous step for Person B.

This shouldn't take too much work since these lists are all shorter than the full list. At this point, the phone should figure it out if the people look different enough. That being said, if it can't now you have to go through the full list and remove people under the wrong record.

If you're finding a lot of entries still present, consider leaving it a night with the phone connected to power to sort through the result of your changes before investing additional time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I'll see how I go with that.